# Coinbase API getBalance ignoring ETC currency

Tags: coinbase-api, coinbase-php

The PHP uses the Coinbase API to get the current balance and list what currencies the account has money in. It has been used for a few weeks now, but since swapping one currency into ETC (Ethereum Classic), the balance ignores this currency. It works for all other currencies I have tried, so what is special about ETC that Coinbase is not returing anything via the API. The coinbase website portfolio does report the ETC balance correctly, so it's definitely a API issue.

```
<?php

include 'cfg.php'; // Contains API key
require_once ('vendor/autoload.php'); // Loads the API libraries

use Coinbase\Wallet\Client as Client;
use Coinbase\Wallet\Configuration as Configuration;
use Coinbase\Wallet\Enum\Param;
use Coinbase\Wallet\Resource\Transaction;

$configuration = Configuration::apiKey($cbase_API_Key, $cbase_API_Secret);
$client = Client::create($configuration);
$stime = $client->getTime();

echo '<h2> Server Time ' . $stime['iso'] . '</h2>';

$balance = 0.00;    
    
$accounts = $client->getAccounts(); // Get the account(s)

echo '<table>';

foreach ( $accounts as $acct )
{
   $amt =  $acct->getBalance()->getAmount() ;
   
   echo '<tr>';
   echo '<td>' . $acct->getCurrency() . '</td>';
   echo '<td>' . $acct->getName() . '</td>';
   echo '<td>' . $acct->getBalance()->getAmount() . '</td>';
   echo '<td>' . $acct->getNativeBalance()->getAmount() . '</td>';
   echo '</tr>';
   $balance = $balance + $acct->getNativeBalance()->getAmount();
}

echo '<table>';
echo '<h2> Total Balance: ' . $balance . '</h2>';

?>
```

Comment: I'm getting this now with GRT after converting from DNT. The website shows the correct info, but the API is missing the GRT end of the transaction. I checked with `getTransactions` and there too the GRT info is not present. Annoying things like this really render the API unreliable. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue came down to pagination:

The fix therefore was to set the pagination limit to 100 (max allowed).

The default is  24, hence why the returned list was incomplete.

`$accounts = $client->getAccounts(['limit' => 100]);`